# Swift: How can I create text with coloured block rectangular background

Tags: ios, swift, background, background-color, nsattributedstring

I have looked into using NSAttributedString but that will colour background based on line length but I would like to create coloured rectangular backgrounds that span width of view/label.

This is how I'd like my text to show with rectangular block coloured backgrounds for each paragraph with white space in between

[image]

Comment: Have you tried label.backgroundColor ?

Comment: From that image I would do a stack view with labels and set their background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to look like your image, you can stack labels in a UIStackView and change all the background color of the labels to your custom color

Answer (score 3):

This would be done by simply changing the .backgroundColor property on the UILabel you're working with.

```
label.backgroundColor = .red
```

If you want some more freedom with the spacing of the label, you can put it inside another view, set the constraints like you want them and then change the .backgroundColor property on the superview you just added.